# How to update YouTube video ID when clicking different play buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube-api

I have a feed full of videos. When a user clicks on a play button, I want that specific video ID to be loaded into the videoID variable found in the YouTube API. Right now, I have managed to program the site to start playing a video for each time the play button is clicked, however, the ID (that is specified as a custom field using ACF `$video_id` when editing the post) does not update. Here's what my feed looks like:

[image: feed]

I've tried adding looking at the `player.loadVideoById` but haven't had much luck.

Here is my YouTube API code:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
        videoId: "HoVWmW0Zdmo",
        playerVars: {
            controls: '0',
            html5: '1',
            cc_load_policy: '0',
            disablekb: '1',
            iv_load_policy: '3',
            modestbranding: '1',
            showinfo: '0',
            rel: '0',
            autoplay: '0',
        },
        events: {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
        }

    });
}

//the id placed below is just a sample id to see if I could even get the ID to change...which I couldnt
jQuery(".media-circle").on("click", function() {
        player.loadVideoById("Vw4KVoEVcr0");
    });
```

Here is a HTML snippet of the play button. the class `.media-circle` is the round shape containing the playpause button that overlays the album artwork.

```
<div class="album-dark-overlay play">
    <div class="media-circle">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I have to pull the post ID so that javascript knows which videoID to look for?

Comment: that's what I'm sort of confused at right now. I am using a custom field where the user adds the videoID while editing a post. And then I make that into a php $video_id = get_field('video_id'). `media-circle` is the circle that surrounds the play button. So when a user clicks anywhere in the area of the circle, the play button (inside the circle) then gets toggled to a pause button (I've done this part successfully). I've also managed to trigger a video to start playing when the play button is toggled, just not the video that is linked to the specific post that was clicked on @NewToJS

Comment: How are you passing the new video `ID`? How is it related to `media-circle` element being clicked?  You need to pass the new video `ID` so the player knows what to play. At the moment you are telling it to play the same video each time `media-circle` is clicked. Why not give `media-circle` an `ID` you can set he `ID` to the video ID, that way when you `media-circle` is click you can target the ID of that element and the player will know which video to play... Example `player.loadVideoById(this.id);`

Comment: @NewToJS my understanding of `loadVideoByID` was that the argument it took was the id of the video (a string of random characters) not the ID of the html element? How would this html element be linked to the video that is found within the post though?

Comment: If you use `player.loadVideoById("Vw4KVoEVcr0");` it will play the video `Vw4KVoEVcr0`. Since you have an onclick eventlistener for all elements with the group of `media-circle` each time you click that element it will continue to load the same video `ID` unless you tell it to play a different `ID`. When you construct the video results/list you need to tell it what video `ID` should play when that function is run. If you give each `media-circle` an `ID` to match the video it should play you can target the `ID` of the element that triggers the function to change/load the new video.

Comment: Here is an example. I have set the ID of the images to the video ID it should play when clicked. Are you can see all of them share the same `media-circle` class. https://jsfiddle.net/u3bntba6/

Comment: @NewToJS that worked, thank you for the example, that helped me understand! If you add a response, I would be happy to accept that as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `player.loadVideoById("Vw4KVoEVcr0");` it will play the video `Vw4KVoEVcr0`.

Since you have an `onclick` event listener for all elements with the group of `media-circle` each time you click that element it will continue to load the same video `ID` unless you tell it to play a different `ID`.

When you construct the video results/list you need to tell it what video `ID` should play when that function is run. If you give each `media-circle` an `ID` to match the video it should play you can target the `ID` of the element that triggers the function to change/load the new video.

---

Here is an example. I have set the `ID` of the images to the video `ID` it should play when clicked. You can see all of them share the same `media-circle` class. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u3bntba6/)

> Demo Source code

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div><hr/>
<img id="ovrGzbsQZqc" class="media-circle" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ovrGzbsQZqc/0.jpg"/>Pegboard Nerds - Emoji VIP [Monstercat Official Music Video]<br>
<img id="YnwsMEabmSo" class="media-circle" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnwsMEabmSo/0.jpg"/> Marshmello - Alone [Monstercat Official Music Video]<br>
<img id="-7Ok0O2nQaA" class="media-circle" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/-7Ok0O2nQaA/0.jpg"/> Pegboard Nerds - Melodymania [Monstercat EP Release]<br>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '200',
        width: '350',
        videoId: 'HoVWmW0Zdmo',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
$(function() {
    jQuery(".media-circle").on("click", function() {
        player.loadVideoById(this.id);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
img{max-height:100p;max-width:150px;}
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!